# What's the purpose of thie ciuculator

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, plumbing-fixture

I will soon need a new water heater, so I'm now trying to understand what I have. I see the water circulator in the picture. It's on an off-shoot of the cold supply. For the first time in ten years of living here I realized that it's always on. What is its likely pupose?

[image]

In response to Gil's response, here's more info. The furthest away bathroom was renovated about three years ago and the pump in the picture below was cut out of the equations. Were these two pieces of equipment working together in tandem? With tho other piece of of the equation, is this one doing anything? The branch that the circulator in the first picture is on - is it an additional line running to that bathroom just for the purposes of circulation?

[image]

Comment: Yet another recirculation loop with zero insulation. That's expensive to run, especially in the summer...

Comment: Does it appear to be working? Do you get hot water with very little delay in some or all of your fixtures? If not, might want to try unplugging it and see if you notice any difference. Running all the time is abnormal and wasteful (they are usually controlled either by a timer, as on the one ripped out, or by a temperature sensor, or the clever setup these days would combine motion sensors and a temperature sensor.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to go only to the tank so it's not possible to back feed into the potable supply?

Answer (score 2):

That is an instant hot configuration. The pump from what I can see is discharging into the cold water inlet of the hot water heater. Check the other end of the tube feeding the pump from above. I expect it will be connected to a hot water line at the far end of your home. There may be several branches. There should also be a check somewhere in the line to prevent water from flowing from the cold back to the hot. The check may be part of the circulator. If it is running all the time the possibility exists the check valve was not installed. I have one similar to that.

Comment: TY. Please see my edits.